# Visual Studio 2013 cannot connect SQL Server when second instance of VS is opened

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I have a strange problems with my Visual Studio (2013 Professional). I'm using SQL Express 2014 and the built in IIS Express on the same machine for a project, and my code works fine in debug mode until I start a second instance of the Visual Studio with a different project opened. From that point the debugging in the first instance stops working, and when I start it I get the following exception:

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]"

It is clearly not a network related (no network involved) and instance specific error (SQL server works fine under usual conditions). Could anyone tell me what is the problem with Visual Studio?

**UPDATE:** I tried to recreate the problem, and I realized that the other opened project is mapped to the same IIS virtual directory and the same port, which implies this problem has nothing to do with SQL connectivity, so the question lost its relevancy. I assume when you use IIS Express VS updates the IIS configuration when you open a project. However I still don't understand why I get an SQL exception (EF5, Code-first, database initialization), when the code is starting up. If someone could explain this, I'll give the bounty.

Comment: If you open a second VS without opening a project in it, do you still get the problem?

Comment: what does your connection string look like ?

Comment: @Rhumborl No. Actually when I tried to reproduce the problem, I realized the second project is set exactly the same IIS port, so maybe this is not even an SQL related error, and the result (sql exception) is misleading

Comment: @Symeon nothing special, I'm kinda sure this is not connection string problem. anyway: Data Source=machine_name\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=db_name;Integrated Security=True

Comment: Its a strange one - i often have multiple instances of VS running different apps all pointing to the same sql server.  Have you tried restarting sql ?

Comment: @Symeon Sorry, I meant the application is mapped the same IIS virtual directory and the same port. So it's not really about SQL

Comment: Ahh ok - that kind of makes sense - if it is running in the same virtual directory it is probably trying to use the same named piped and therefore falling over, although you have two VS run up - iis express runs up by virtual directory.  Glad you have solved it.

Comment: @Symeon I didn't really solve it. I mean the other opened project have never started so it should not interfere with the running application and the exception is very misleading. Something is happening in IIS and VS under the hood, and it is beyond my understanding. However I changed the IIS port, and the problem went away, so in the end of the day, it is some kind of a solution.

Comment: @kexx VS does indeed remap the virtual directory in IIS when you open the project - you don't need to run it for this to happen, so the problem looks more like in the second project. You say the debugging stops (makes sense because of the remap) and then you get the error when you start it - at this point you are debugging project1 but actually running project2!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the problem, and I realized that the other opened project is mapped to the same IIS virtual directory and the same port, which implies this problem has nothing to do with SQL connectivity, so the question lost its relevancy. I assume when you use IIS Express VS updates the IIS configuration when you open a project. However I still don't understand why I get an SQL exception (EF5, Code-first, database initialization), when the code is starting up. If someone could explain this, I'll give the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the second instance of VS 2013 try to connect to SQL server using other credentials so connect :)  i.e.try to change the port

Comment: Thanks, but I'm kinda sure that the connection string is not involved in this problem